# No faces appearing on my model in UV editor

Tags: uv

usually when I go into the UV editor, it will appear like this:
[image]

I'm able to see which faces of my mesh correlate to which part of the texture image. However, I have another model where this is not the case at all. Everything looks to be a mess and faces also don't appear on the model so I have no idea which faces are on which part of the texture image... How do I get model 2 to be like model 1?

[image]

Here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/73bf513a66d4419c9b95d6e8404c8ca3

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have turned off 'Show overlays' by accident.

Without it turned on:
[image]

With it turned on:
[image]

This function is there to easily check your scene without all the assisting overlay graphics. For instance, when you're working in Eevee and you want to see the final result while moving through your scene, you can easily turn the overlays off to get the ultimate viewing experience.

Hope this helps!